# Are deeply nested polymorphic resources worth the effort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, custom-routes, nested-routes

I am at the point in my development that I am thinking that deeply (>1) nested resources are not worth the effort.

I have something like this:

```
  resources :first-level do
    resources :comments
    resources :second-level do
      resources :comments      
      resources :first-child do
        resources :comments
      end
      resources :second-child do
        resources :comments
      end
      resources :third-child do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
```

The kicker is that the comments are polymorphic to the other resources.  My intent was to have clean looking URLs like ~/first-level/34/comments, ~/first-level/34/second-level/56/third-level/comments etc.

The problem so far is the polymorphic routes when nested cause nothing but grief.  I am following a couple of Ryan Bates Railscasts as an example.  For example if I try to use polymorphic_path on the first level it works fine and I get:

```
polymorphic_path([@commentable, comments]) => ~/first-level/34/comments
```

but the same code on `~/first-level/34/second-level/23` fails with:

`undefined method 'second-level_comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcc4acfbe58>:0x007fcc4ae73d08>` but when I look at my routes the actual named route is `first-level_second-level_comment`.  I tried to manually create that `second-level_comment_path` to basically alias to `first-level_second-level_comment` but I could not seem to make that work either.

Unless someone can point out an obvious error here I am leaning towards this approach (http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) and just un-nesting these.  I have a breadcrumb style navigation to show the hiearchy so that should suffice and the more I look at it the urls do get a bit unwieldily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nested resources, you will need to specify all the parent levels when you want to access a child level. Otherwise Rails will not know how to get to your child level. So, you will need to use first-level_second-level_comment and supply first-level and second-level values like this:

```
first-level_second-level_comments_path(@my_first_level, @my_second_level)
```

will render:

```
~/first-level/34/second-level/23/comments
```

EDIT:

I don't see why you will need to build path incrementally.

You can always build first_level comments path:

```
first-level_comments_path(@my_first_level)
```

will render

```
~/first-level/34/comments
```

Or listing of all second levels within the first level: (second-level's index action for a given first-level)

```
first-level_second-levels_path(@my_first_level)
```

will render

```
~/first-level/34/second-levels
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I started to un-nest my resources and then quicky discovere that it was easier to struggle through the troubles with the nesting.  With a given nested resource is there an easy was to reconstruct the hierarchy of the path i.e. first_second_third_etc_path?